# How to add single inverted comma after column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, single-quotes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMxf2.png)

I want to print the statement like [Emp_name's  salary is .....]  ex.- Aniket's salary is...

What will be the syntax for this?

I have tried this SQL:

```
select empname + 's''salary is' + cast(salary as varchar) 
from emp
```

but it's not working

Comment: "not working" is not a good problem description. Do you get any errors? Then please include them. Is the output not what you want? Then show and explain that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select empname+ '''s salary is' + cast(salary as varchar) from emp
```